@Mapperアノテーションをつけているのにマッパーが見つからない
JavaのSpring Bootで@mapperを使用しているのに、Mapperが見つからないエラーになってしまいます。
下記のようなエラーが表示されます。
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field BookMapper in com.example.demo.service.BookService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.BookMapper' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.BookMapper' in your configuration.

＜要約＞
BookServiceクラス内のBookMapperフィールドに対する依存性注入が失敗しました。SpringコンテナがBookMapper型のBeanを見つけられないためです。BookMapperのBeanが適切に定義されていることを確認してください。

@Mapperを使用しているのはBookMapper.javaです。(画像張ってあります)
どのように改善すれば良いかアドバイスお願いします。






build.gradle ファイルの中身はどうなっていますか？画面のキャプチャでなく文字列として貼り付けてください。また、既に存在する何らかのコードを参考にしているように思われますが、提示可能であれば何を見て書いたコードなのか示してください。

@user62462 Gradle でも Maven でも、XML ファイルは src/main/java ではなく src/main/resources 内に配置する必要があります（あまりお勧めはしませんが カスタマイズ は可能です）。
先のコメントでも指摘されていますが、画像の使用は欠点が多いので極力避けた方が良いです。
